# Use of the word "venture" in this context

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, word-order

Looking at the word venture here:

> "It smells a bit musty," ventured William after a moment's silence.

It seems as if to mean "to dare say something."

So would it be good situation to use this verb when we critize our boss at work by saying like:

> "The newbie guy at office ventured the CEO's opinion on the new product is not supportive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right it also means "to dare say something".

As for the sentence "The newbie guy at office ventured the CEO's opinion on the project is not supportive", please note that "newbie" is a countable noun, not an adjective. I think the correct sentence is "The newbie at office ventured that the CEO's opinion on the project  was (not is)  not supportive".

Comment: @ Thank you Khan.Can we say " somebody venture somebody that.."  for example  " she ventured me that I am not beautiful enough for the beauty contest"  or  " she ventured to say to me that I am not beautiful enough for the beauty contest "

Comment: @Murat - The _verb_ venture doesn't take an object like that. Think of it this way: _I **dared** to tell our boss the bad news. I **had the courage** to tell our boss the bad news. I **ventured** to tell our boss the bad news._ Those three sentences all mean the same thing.